# QGroupBox weirdly placed in QLayout

Tags: qt, qt4

I found a weird bug that I cannot explain where I did something wrong.
Maybe you can help me with that.

Basically i have a `QGroupBox` in `QVBoxLayout` inside another that is part of another ... you get the deal when you see the image ...

[image: Layout of the group when placed using QtDesigner]

The `QGroupBox` contains 3 fixed `QComboBox` objects, and is used in multiple views inside the UI (using `layout->addWidget(group)`) to filter data and it is where it should be, how it should be. In one case I need to add another `QComboBox` to a placeholder layout using `placeholder->addWidget(additionalFilterCmb);` before adding the group to the other layout.

Now the group gets displayed in the right place but ... see by yourself...
[image: How it looks in the application]

Do you know what could cause that behaviour and maybe how to fix that?

Done so far:

- called `QWidget::adjustSize()` on the groupBox
- `QResizeEvents` are posted from the containing layouts and called from itself as 'sending object' when window gets resized, minimized or
  maximized

QResizeEvents are posted from the containing layouts and called from itself as 'sending object' when window gets resized, minimized or
   maximized

cheers Zai

Comment: Did you try to use QWidget::adjustSize() after insertion the new combo box?

Comment: Do you not like the smaller spacing or the bottom widget overlaying the last combobox? Or is it the margin left and right to the group box?

Comment: @vahancho: i did but it turned out to result in same behaviour.

Comment: @SebastianLange: it is that above the group is 'a ton' of space and below it gets overlapped

Comment: When you change size of window problem persists? Do you have some code which alters position of widgets? Best would be instal event filter on `QGroupBox` to observe its geometry and check call stack if something else then layout changes it.

Comment: @MarekR i tried resizing, minimize and maximizing the window, still the same. i do not change position of widgets, i had some function to resize splitters at a time but that is removed long ago. ill try that event filter

Comment: @MarekR good idea, but unfortunatly nothing unexpected happened. the mainwindow, its layouts and splitters cause the posting of `QResizeEvent`s to the comboBox